# How to address a category to the field I select in the query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Not sure if possible, but I have a table that looks like following:

```
URL | amount | date | ...........
```

The value URL could be a URL that looks like the following:

```
https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory1/....... | 1243 | 01-01-1999
https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory2/....... | 4325 | 01-02-1999
https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory2/....... | 23 | 01-02-1999
https://www.example.com/category2/subcategory1/....... | 12543 | 01-01-1999
https://www.example.com/category2/subcategory2/....... | 124453 | 01-01-1999
```

How can I get a result where I group/categorize the URLs already in the query? the result I am looking for is:

```
category1 | average(amount) | 01-01-1999
category1 | average(amount) | 01-02-1999
category2 | average(amount) | 01-01-1999
```

Working on Google BigQuery and looking for a sample query that could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we split the url by `'/'`, then this appears to be the fourth element.  So:

```
select split(url, '/')[ordinal(4)] as category, date, avg(amount)
from t
group by category, date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, CONCAT(r'', NET.REG_DOMAIN(url), '/([^/]*)/')) AS category, 
  AVG(amount) AS avg_amount, date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY category, date
```

Note, above solution also covers cases like below

```
www.example.com/category2/subcategory2/......., 124453, '01-01-1999'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create temporal table

```
declare @t table (category varchar, amount bigint, date date)
```

2. Insert processed data from source table.

```
 insert into @t
 select f_findSring(column1) -- this function returns category1, category2 and so...
       ,amount
       ,date
```

3. Query from temporal table

```
 select category
        ,average(amount)
        ,date
from @t
group by category, date
```